# Fazer upload de arquivo .mp3 para servidor PHP em Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, upload, iphone

Como eu faço para fazer upload de um arquivo .mp3 em meu iphone para meu servidor utilizando uma pagina de upload eu consegui fazer com imagens mais não estou conseguindo fazer com arquivos .mp3 alguém poderia ma ajudar?
Segue o abaixo o código que utilizo:

**Objective-C:**

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgFoto.image, 90);

NSString *urlString = @"http://127.0.0.1:8888/uploadsom/upload.php";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"
;
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];//imageData
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
```

**Pagina PHP**

```
<?php
$uploaddir = './uploads/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']); $uploadfile = $uploaddir .    $file;
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) { 
echo "http://meusite.com.br/uploads/{$file}";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Mude a codificação de imagem do topo:**

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgFoto.image, 90);
```

Para dados genéricos, nesse caso o áudio:

```
NSString *audioFilePath = @""; // caminho local de onde o arquivo está armazenado
NSData *audioData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:audioFilePath];
```

Por quê? Como o nome da função apontava, você estava pegando informações binárias de uma Imagem JPEG. E agora de qualquer tipo de arquivo binário (audio, vídeo, etc).

Mude a linha:

```
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Para:

```
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"file.mp3\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Por quê? Apenas um detalhe, já que foi mudado o nome do arquivo a ser enviado de ipodfile.jpg para file.mp3, identificando que é um arquivo mp3.

**Mude:**

```
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];//imageData
```

Para:

```
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:audioData]];
```

Por quê? Anexando a nova audioData criada.

Comment: Muito obrigado  Alfred Baudisch, funcionou perfeito me quebrou um galho.

Comment: Que bom @BrunoRichart. Só peço então que marque a minha resposta como a escolhida, pra assim sua pergunta dar como concluída e respondida.